# java script alerts always appear

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

## above the form

```
<?php require_once "core-admin/init-admin.php";

if( !isset($_SESSION['admin_username']) ){
        $_SESSION['msg'] = 'page can not open';
        header('Location:admin_login.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']) ){
        $press_type        = $_POST['press_type'];
        $press_picture    = $_FILES['press_picture'];
        $type_file            = $_FILES['press_picture'] ['type'];
        $tmp_file             = $_FILES['press_picture']['tmp_name'];
        $file_size               = $_FILES['press_picture'] ['size'];

        if(!empty(trim($press_type)) ) {
           if(!empty($_FILES['press_picture']['tmp_name']) ){
               if($type_file == "image/jpeg" || $type_file == "image/png" || $type_file == "image/jpg" ){
                 if($file_size <= 300000){

                   if(add_press($press_type, $press_picture)) {
    $message = 'sukses men.';
echo "<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'>
                        alert('$message');
                window.location.replace(\"add_data_press.php\");
                                        </SCRIPT>";
}
                             } else {  ?>
                              <script>
                          alert("failed add data");
                            </script>
                        <?php }
                      }else{ ?>
                        <script>
                    alert("size should be below 200kb");
                      </script>

            <?php }
                  }else{ ?>
                     <script>
                        alert("image type should be .jpeg .jpg atau .png");
                    </script>
            <?php   }
                }else{ ?>
                <script>
            alert("image can not be empty");
                </script>
<?php }
          }else{ ?>
            <script>
        alert("please complete the unfilled form");
          </script>
          <?php
          }
?>
```

## form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../view/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../view/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../view/css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../view/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">


</head>



<body>
<?php require_once"../view/header-admin.php";?>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content if tdk ada ini tidak akan tampil apa apa -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <i class="fa fa-th text-danger" aria-hidden="" id="menu-toggle"></i>


<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
              <h1 class="display-4">Carolyn Tyler</h1>
              <h6>handmade fine jewelry</h6>
              <br>
              <h5>Add data press</h5>



      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="formGroupExampleInput">Press Type</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Press Type" name="press_type" required="">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">press picture</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" name="press_picture">
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>

          <br> <br>


          </form>

        </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

my problem is, when i access this page. I always get the alert "please complete the unfilled form". in this case I have not done any insert yet but have alerted this page.

but if I split the file # abovethepage # alerts do not show up again. is there any way to make # abovethepage # files still on 1 page but alert does not appear again.?

Comment: because it's in the else of your isset($_POST) so when you don't have any POST it will show

Comment: do not understand. but at the time I split that file and access the page through the insert all worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you check `isset($_POST['submit'])` is return false on first time page load

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

thats why your else part run first time page load without submitting `form data`

Answer (score 0):

When you access the page for the first time, the $_POST is empty(It will only contain data if you send HTTP POST request to your script using submit button). In such case, the below else condition satisfies:

```
else{ ?>
    <script>
alert("please complete the unfilled form");
  </script>
  <?php
  }
```

This is why it always shows the alert message.